# How does one refer to a global variable bearing the same name as a local one inside the body of a function?

Tags: c, variables, scope, global-variables, local-variables

What if we define a global variable
`int  x;`
and inside the body of a function define another variable `int x;`.

Inside the function 'x' would always refer to the local variable 'x'. Now if the user must refer to the global variable x inside the very function how does one achieve that?

Comment: Why is this tagged as both C and Python?

Comment: In C you can't. If you have hidden a symbol then there's no way to access it.

Comment: why do u need the same name as a variable?

Comment: How about next time you insert the question title into Google search box first.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, removed, thanks for mentioning, I'll keep things in mind for sure.

Comment: You refer to it as 'a mistake'

Answer (score 2):

> Since your question is tagged "C", I'll answer about that language. Other languages may provide syntactic sugar or mechanisms to do what you want.

Defining a variable using the name of a variable existing in a greater scope is called **shadowing**: the inner definition *shadows* the outer one.

Below is an example:

```
int x = 42;

int main() {
    int x = 0; // Here, `x` shadows the global `x`.
    printf("%d\n", x); // Prints '0'
}
```

In C, there is no way to get the value of the shadowed variable.

On the style plan, shadowing is often considered a bad practice since it makes your code less legible and harder to refactor.

Comment: Correct. Please change "As far as I know," into "In C," as there is no way in C to get to the shadowed variable.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this. :)